# How can I connect to a local server via Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, smb

I'm remote connecting to a server on my local network.

On Mac, I'm using this method:

Finder -> Go -> Connect to server and server address I enter that:

> smb://192.168.XX.YY

It doesn't ask password and I can login as Guest. Then it asks which folder I want to go. By selecting the folder (Volumes/folder) it opens.

There is no problem on that, it works for Mac.

Now, I want to use a Windows (8) computer to make connection to the same server.

I used the remote desktop connection and enter the IP address but it couldn't connect.

**How can I connect to the server via Windows Remote Desktop Connection?**

Comment: It sounds like you're accessing file shares, not remote desktop. To do the equivalent on windows, you can just Start -> Run `\\192.168.XX.YY` which should open an explorer window connected to that server.

Comment: This is not related to programming and does not belong on StackOverflow. Voting to close and move to [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer and it works:

> It sounds like you're accessing file shares, not remote desktop.
>
> To do the equivalent on windows, you can just **Start -> Run
>   \192.168.XX.YY** which should open an explorer window connected to that
>   server.